# C++ glibc corrupted double linked list at the point of a throw statement

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, glibc, throw

I know this has something to do with memory accessing and allocation, but it seems that this occurs precisely at the two throw statements... i don't understand why....

```
void RolePlayingGame::initializeMonsters( unsigned int seed, unsigned int numMon){

    RandomNumberGenerator ran( seed, this->dungeon.getWorldRows()-2 );
    RandomNumberGenerator ran2( seed, this->dungeon.getWorldColumns()-2 );
    unsigned r, c;
    bool done = false;
    string str("Enter an integer from 0 to 10. How many monsters should be added: ");
    char mons[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

    do{
        try{
            cout<<" in try"<<endl;
            if( numMon >= 11 )
                throw 1;

            if( !cin )
                throw str;

            done = true;
            nrMonsters = numMon;
            nrm = numMon;

            monsters = new Creature[nrMonsters];

            for ( unsigned i = 0; i < nrMonsters; ++i ){
                do{
                    r = ran.nextInt();
                    c = ran2.nextInt();
                }while( (dungeon.getMazeSquare(r, c) != ' ') || (creatures[r][c] != 0) );

                dungeon.setMazeSquare(r,c,mons[i]);
                creatures[r][c] = &monsters[i];
            }
        }catch( std::string s1 ){
            cout<<"in catch 1"<<endl;
            cout<<endl<<s1;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(100,'\n');
            cin>>numMon;
        }catch( int ){
            cout<<"in catch 2"<<endl;
            cout<<endl<<"Too many monsters requested. Maximum 10 allowed."<<endl<<"How many monsters should be added: ";
            cin>>numMon;
        }
    }while( !done );
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of `creatures` and how you initialize it.

Comment: void RolePlayingGame::initializeCreatures(){
 
 creatures = new Creature**[dungeon.getWorldRows()];
 
 for( unsigned i = 0; i < dungeon.getWorldColumns(); ++i ){
 creatures[i] = new Creature*[dungeon.getWorldColumns()];
 }
 
 for( unsigned i = 0; i < dungeon.getWorldRows(); ++i ){
 for ( unsigned j = 0; j < dungeon.getWorldColumns();   ++j )
 {   creatures[i][j] = 0;
 }
}

Comment: private:
    Dungeon dungeon;
    Creature hero;
    Creature* monsters; 
    Creature* firstAidKits;
    Creature*** creatures; 
    unsigned int nrMonsters;
    unsigned int nrFirstAidKits;
    unsigned int healthBoost;
    unsigned int maxHealth;

Comment: Your first level of array is sized based on `getWorldRows` but you're accessing it in the loop that loops `getWorldColumns` times.